# "Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build a api for updating first and last name for my user. I am getting the following error in HTTP Response

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."
    ]
}
```

I have written the following API and trying to pass the patch request to it.

```
class UserSelfUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [UserPermissions, ]

    def update(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
        serializer = UserUpdateSerializer(instance, data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response({'success': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The serializer for the above request is:

```
class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields: ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

The format in which I am trying to pass my request body is:

```
{
    "first_name": "A",
    "last_name": "B"
}
```

The reason for using

> instance = User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)

is because I want the functionality in a way that only logged in user is able to modify his details only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is here

```
serializer = UserUpdateSerializer(instance, data=request.data, many=True)
```

change to

```
serializer = UserUpdateSerializer(instance, data=request.data)
```

if passing `many=True` you need to pass a queryset not an instance